# recyclerview is flipping upside down after button is clicked

Tags: android, firebase, android-fragments, android-recyclerview

i have a Recyclerview  that is taking data from Firebase the Recyclerview had edit text inside it when i click the fab button a for loop iterate over the edit text inside the Recyclerview and save the data inside the Firebase 
my problem is when the button is clicked half of the recyclerview is mirrored

```
    FirebaseUser user = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();
    final String userid = user.getUid();
    usersDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("users").child(userid);
    recyclerView = view.findViewById(R.id.jardiList);

    AItem = new ArrayList<>();

    aAdapter = new jardiListAdapter(getContext(), AItem, this);
    aAdapter.setHasStableIds(true);
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getContext()));
    recyclerView.setAdapter(aAdapter);
    fab = view.findViewById(R.id.fab_jardi);


    fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            for (int i = 0; i < AItem.size(); i++) {
                Adapterp mylist = AItem.get(i);
                View view1 = recyclerView.getChildAt(i);
                if (view1 != null) {
                    final TextView Qty = view1.findViewById(R.id.jSoldQty);
                    Map<String, Object> note6 = new HashMap<>();
                    note6.put(KEY_ITEMNAME, mylist.getItemName());
                    note6.put(KEY_ITEMOLD, mylist.getPurchasedQty());

                    int a =  Integer.valueOf(mylist.getPurchasedQty())-Integer.valueOf(mylist.getItemStill()) ;
                    Qty.setText(String.valueOf(a));
                    mylist.setItemStill(String.valueOf(a));
                    // note6.put(KEY_ITEMPRICE, mylist.getItemPrice());
                    if (mylist.getItemStill() == null) {
                        note6.put(KEY_ITEMSTILL, "0");
                        note6.put(KEY_ITEMSOLD, "0");
                        note6.put(KEY_SALESTOTAL, "0");
                    } else {

                        note6.put(KEY_ITEMSTILL, mylist.getItemStill());
                        note6.put(KEY_ITEMSOLD, mylist.getItemSold());
                        note6.put(KEY_SALESTOTAL, mylist.getSalesTotal());
                        //      currentTotal = currentTotal + Integer.valueOf(mylist.getSalesTotal());
                    }
                    note6.put(KEY_DATE, getDate());
                    //  note.put(KEY_TIME, mylist.getPurchasedQty());
                    //  note.put(KEY_P, mylist.getPurchasedQty());

                    usersDatabase.child("jardi").child(getDate()).child(p).child("Cigarette").child(mylist.getItemID()).updateChildren(note6);
                    usersDatabase.child("jardi1").child(p).child("Cigarette").child(mylist.getItemID()).updateChildren(note6);

                }

            }


        }
    });
```

**EDIT:**  i forget to to say that i only face the problem in portrait mode in landscape its works normal without flipping

**EDIT:**

```
 usersDatabase.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            if (p.equals("1")) {
                itemsDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("users").child(userid)
                        .child("inventory").child("p").child(p).child("Cigarette");
                itemsDatabase.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                        AItem.clear();
                        for (DataSnapshot teacherSnapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                            Adapterp adapterp = teacherSnapshot.getValue(Adapterp.class);
                            adapterp.setKey(teacherSnapshot.getKey());
                            AItem.add(adapterp);
                        }
                        aAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();


                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

                    }
                });
```

EDIT : this is the jardiListAdapter.class

```
public class jardiListAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<jardiListAdapter.RecyclerViewHolder> {

private Context mContext;
private List<Adapterp> item;
private OnItemClickListener mListener;

public jardiListAdapter(Context context, List<Adapterp> uploads, OnItemClickListener mListener1) {
    mContext = context;
    item = uploads;
    mListener = mListener1;
}

@Override
public jardiListAdapter.RecyclerViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View v = LayoutInflater.from(mContext).inflate(R.layout.jardi_adapter, parent, false);
    return new jardiListAdapter.RecyclerViewHolder(v);
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(final jardiListAdapter.RecyclerViewHolder holder, int position) {
    final Adapterp currentitem = item.get(position);
    holder.itemName.setText(currentitem.getItemName());
    holder.old.setText(currentitem.getPurchasedQty());
    holder.still.setText(currentitem.getItemStill());
    if(!holder.still.getText().toString().equals("")){
        int sum = Integer.valueOf(currentitem.getPurchasedQty())-Integer.valueOf(currentitem.getItemStill());
       holder.sold.setText(String.valueOf(sum));
    }
    if(currentitem.getSalesTotal()!=null){
        NumberFormat formatter = new DecimalFormat("#,###");
        double price = Double.valueOf(currentitem.getSalesTotal());
        String formattedNumber = formatter.format(price);
        holder.salestotal.setText(formattedNumber);
    }else {
        holder.salestotal.setText("0");
    }




}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return item.size();
}

public void setOnItemClickListener(OnItemClickListener listener) {
    this.mListener = listener;
}

public interface OnItemClickListener {
    void onItemClick(int position, String newValue);

    void onShowItemClick(int position);

    void onDeleteItemClick(int position);
}

public class RecyclerViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener
        , MenuItem.OnMenuItemClickListener, PopupMenu.OnMenuItemClickListener {
    public TextView itemName, old, sold, salestotal;
    public EditText still;
    public String cc;
    ImageButton optionBtn;

    public RecyclerViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);

        itemName = itemView.findViewById(R.id.jitemname);
        old = itemView.findViewById(R.id.jOldQty);
        sold = itemView.findViewById(R.id.jSoldQty);
        salestotal = itemView.findViewById(R.id.jSalesTotal);
        still = itemView.findViewById(R.id.jStillQty);
        optionBtn = itemView.findViewById(R.id.jardi_option);
        optionBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                showPopup(v);
            }
        });
        still.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {

            }

            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable editable) {
                mListener.onItemClick(getAdapterPosition(), still.getText().toString());

            }
        });


        itemView.setOnClickListener(this);


    }


    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onMenuItemClick(MenuItem item) {
        if (mListener != null) {
            int position = getAdapterPosition();
            if (position != RecyclerView.NO_POSITION) {

                switch (item.getItemId()) {
                    case R.id.smallJardi_btn:
                        mListener.onShowItemClick(position);
                        break;
                    case R.id.jardi_missingPurchases_btn:
                        mListener.onShowItemClick(position);
                        break;
                }
            }
        }
        return false;
    }

    public void showPopup(View view) {
        PopupMenu popup = new PopupMenu(mContext, view);
        try {
            // Reflection apis to enforce show icon
            Field[] fields = popup.getClass().getDeclaredFields();
            for (Field field : fields) {
                String POPUP_CONSTANT = "mPopup";
                if (field.getName().equals(POPUP_CONSTANT)) {
                    field.setAccessible(true);
                    Object menuPopupHelper = field.get(popup);
                    Class<?> classPopupHelper = Class.forName(menuPopupHelper.getClass().getName());
                    String POPUP_FORCE_SHOW_ICON = "setForceShowIcon";
                    Method setForceIcons = classPopupHelper.getMethod(POPUP_FORCE_SHOW_ICON, boolean.class);
                    setForceIcons.invoke(menuPopupHelper, true);
                    break;
                }
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        popup.getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.jardi_menu, popup.getMenu());
        popup.setOnMenuItemClickListener(this);
        popup.show();
    }


}
}
```

and this is my layouts

jardi_adapter.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:visibility="visible"
app:cardBackgroundColor="#FFFFE8">

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:weightSum="1.7">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/jitemname"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="0.4"
        android:padding="8dp"
        android:textColor="#fa0" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/jOldQty"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="0.2"
        android:padding="8dp" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/jStillQty"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="0.3"
        android:inputType="number"
        android:padding="8dp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/jSoldQty"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="0.2"
        android:padding="8dp"
        android:text="0" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/jSalesTotal"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="0.2"
        android:padding="8dp"
        android:text="0" />

    <TextView

        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="0.2"
        android:padding="8dp"
        android:text="LBP" />

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/jardi_option"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="0.2"
        android:background="#00000000"
        android:src="@drawable/arrow_24dp" />
</LinearLayout>

<View
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="1dp"
    android:background="@color/black" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Can you add some screen shots

Comment: sure but what i forget to to say that i only face the problem in portrait mode in landscape its works normal without flipping

Comment: this is a video what is happening   https://youtu.be/grWbLJH1mVw

Comment: is the video clear ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a an issue when you were using the edit text in recycler list. When you scroll down the bottom edit text in the recycler view will be filled with already filled edit text value, even though you user is not filled.

As a work around You can create some sparse array any data structure which will best suitable for you, that can map you position and value like mEditTextItem[] = new String [LIST_SIZE]. , assuming that position of ur list item matches with index of array.

Try updating the index with the value of text watcher mEditTextItem[POSITION] = YOUR_EDIT_TEXT_VALUE

When you want to initialize your edit text use the value by mEditTextItem[POSITION]

You can always make sure that your edit text will be having the right value by this .

On fab item click instead of iterating through the recycler view, iterate through mEditTextItem for the result

Comment: i should iterate through recyclerview because i am taking data from the recyclerview.adapter and the edittext at the same time please check the video for what is happening  youtu.be/grWbLJH1mVw

Comment: @AhmadBaddah You can create the array or list in the adapter class. When ever binding view update from mEditTextItem[] array and on TextWatcher implementation you can update the mEditTextItem. So you will be having mEditTextItem[] with the updated value. Now when you need the value of the edit text, mEditTextItem [] will be having updated value of edit text. Instead of iterating recycler view you should iterate through mEditTextItem of your adapter class

Comment: okay what are you saying i made it before but what i am facing is that in the video you will see sales total which should take the updated data from recyclerview and make calculation on firebase (FIFO First In First Out sales value) so i should iterate through the recyclerview

Comment: i just need a solution for the mirroring of the recyclerview and i think the solution is in the recyclerview.setlayoutmanager

Comment: can you please just tell me how to implement what did you said

Comment: how is your jardiListAdapter looks like? Why are you using 
  View view1 = recyclerView.getChildAt(i); and iterating through the items.

Comment: I could not find the reason for mirroring from your code

Comment: thank you for replying i reviewd my code and find the problem the problem was that i used addValueEventListener which was editing the recyclerview after data changed i edit it to addListenerForSingleValueEvent

Comment: thank you very much for your help also i reviewed what you had said can you please be more detailed because it could help me and your answer will be the accepted answer but just be more detailed what i need how to assign an id for the edittext and after it pass the index or position

Comment: i have analyzed my code what is happening is that when that data changed in the Firebase without clicking on any of the edit text the list dosnt flip but if i touched any of the edit text without adding any value just tap on the edit text and then change the value in Firebase the recyclerview goes upside down and then return to its same position as shown in the video... why when i click on edit text this happen help me my problem isn't solved completely

Comment: youtu.be/grWbLJH1mVw  this is the vedio link